# How to show that metrics $d$ and $\min(1,d)$ are topologically equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

I have the following problem in my textbook:

Show that if $(X,d)$ is a metric space then the metric $d_1(x,y):=\min(1,d(x,y))$ is topologically equivalent to $d$.

> I know that 2 metrics are equivalent on $X$ if the open sets in $(X,d)$ and $(X,d_1)$ coincide.

I also have the following theorem:

> Suppose that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are two metrics on $X$. Then the following statements are equivalent:
> (i) The open sets in $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ coincide;
> (ii) For any metric space $(Y,d)$, a function $g:X\to Y$ is continuous from $(X,d_1)$ into $(Y,d)$ iff $g$ is continuous from $(X,d_2)$ into $(Y,d)$; (iii) For any metric space $(Y,d)$, any $f:Y\to X$ is continuous from $(Y,d)$ into $(X,d_1)$ iff $f$ is continuous from $(Y,d)$ into $(X,d)$

So my strategy to prove the problem is to show that (ii) is true.

For this we will need the definition of continuity, so here it is:

We have that a function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at every point $p\in X$ when the following is true for all $p$:

$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0$ such that:

$$d_X(x,p)<\delta \Rightarrow d_Y(f(x),f(p))<\epsilon$$

Here is my attempt to solve this problem:

Let $P$ be the following statement:

$$d(x,p)<\delta \Rightarrow d(g(x),g(p))<\epsilon$$

Let $Q$ be the following statement:

$$d_1(x,p)<\delta \Rightarrow d_1(g(x),g(p))<\epsilon$$

We will now show that $P\Rightarrow Q$:

There are 2 cases to consider:

$1$st case is when $d(x,p)>1$:

This means that $d_1(x,p)=1$

If we set $\epsilon = \delta >1$ then the following statement is true:

$$d_1(x,p)=1<\delta = \epsilon \Rightarrow d_1(g(x),g(p))<\epsilon$$

Since $d_1(g(x),g(p))$ is at most $1$.

$2$nd case is when $d(x,p)<1$. Then the following statement

$$d_1(x,p)=d(x,p)<\delta \Rightarrow d_1(g(x),g(p))<\epsilon$$

is true. To show this, we have 2 subcases:

Case $2.1$: When $d(g(x),g(p))<1$ then by assumption the above statement is true.

Case $2.2$: When $d(g(x),g(p))>1$ then $d_1(g(x),g(y))=1$ and hence if we set $\delta = \epsilon >1$ then $$d(x,p)<1<\delta \Rightarrow d_1(g(x),g(p))<\epsilon$$ is true.

Hence $P \Rightarrow Q$.

> Is it correct until this point?

Now I'm struggling to prove the converse $(Q\Rightarrow P)$. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In metric spaces, two metrics are equivalents if the have the same convergent sequences.

---

Let $(x_n)$ that converges to $x$ for $d$. Let $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. There is $N\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $d(x_n,x)<\varepsilon $ for all $n\geq N$. In particular, $d_1(x_n,x)<\varepsilon $ for all $n\geq N$, and thus $(x_n)$ converges for $d_1$.

I let you prove that if $(x_n)$ converges for $d_1$, then it converges for $d$.

Comment: Is _topologically_ equivalent the same as just equivalent? Since the definition in my textbook says that they are topologically equivalent if the open sets in $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ coincide

Comment: Oh, I see now from the wikipedia page that strong equivalence implies topological equivalence

Comment: Your opening paragraph (which defines what is sometimes called *bilipschitz equivalence*) has nothing to do with this problem. The metrics $d$ and $d_1$ in the question are not bilipschitz equivalence if $d$ is unbounded, for example if $d$ is the standard metric on Euclidean space.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Indeed, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another proof.

We know well the fact that a metric topology is generated by *all* of its open balls (or, in other words, that the set of open balls is a basis for the metric topology). But it's also true, and pretty easy to prove, that for any $R>1$ a metric topology is also generated just by its balls of radius $< R$.

The metrics $d$ and $d_1$ have the exact same set of open balls of radius $<1$, so the metric topologies generated by $d$ and $d_1$ are identical.